# Playframework: activator dist taking too long from within docker container

Tags: docker, playframework, playframework-2.0, dockerfile, typesafe-activator

I have created a container image for building the project, with the following interim image I have pushed to dockerhub somasundaramsekar/play-activator-1.3.0:v1.2.

When I run `docker run -t -i <Image~> ./run.sh` where the image is built using the below Dockerfile

```
FROM somasundaramsekar/play-activator-1.3.0:v1.2
MAINTAINER somasundaram@outlook.com

WORKDIR /application

ADD app ./app
ADD conf ./conf
ADD project ./project
ADD public ./public
ADD test ./test
ADD activator.properties build.sbt ./
ADD run.sh ./
```

and the content of the run.sh is

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH=$PATH:/root/activator-dist-1.3.10/bin
activator dist
```

which is very very very slow!!! the same is the case with sbt clean compile too.

usually stuck at

```
downloading file:/root/activator-dist-1.3.10/repository/org.scala-lang/jline/2.10.6/jars/jline.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#jline;2.10.6!jline.jar (54ms)
downloading file:/root/activator-dist-1.3.10/repository/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.4/jars/jansi.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4!jansi.jar (13ms)
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-scala
    confs: [default]
    5 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (24494kB/166ms)
[info] Loading project definition from /application/project
```

no clue at all for me.. appreciate any help

Comment: sbt is such a lousy tool, any alternatives that is as native to scala as sbt

Comment: What are you using to build? Docker toolbox on VirtualBox? Docker for Windows|Mac ?   Also, check .dockerignore to avoid piecemeal ADD lines in your Dockerfile. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/dockerignore-file